# How to avoid loading actual image before preloader image in mozilla firefox using Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, firefox, preloader

I am using preloader to display loading gif image before loading the actual image. This is working correctly in all browsers except mozilla firefox. In mozilla firefox, actual image is loading first and stays for a second, then the preloader image gets displayed and then again actual image is displayed. I am facing this problem only on integrating it in Ruby On Rails. Any help or guidelines will be appreciated. Please help me.

Below is the jquery code, which i am using for preloader :

```
$.fn.preloader = function(options){
var defaults = {
                 delay:20,
                 preload_parent:"a",
                 check_timer:300,
                 ondone:function(){ },
                 oneachload:function(image){  },
                 fadein:500 
                };

// variables declaration and precaching images and parent container
 var options = $.extend(defaults, options),
 root = $(this) , images = root.find("img").css({"visibility":"hidden",opacity:0}) ,  timer ,  counter = 0, i=0 , checkFlag = [] , delaySum = options.delay ,

 init = function(){

    timer = setInterval(function(){

        if(counter>=checkFlag.length)
        {
        clearInterval(timer);
        options.ondone();
        return;
        }

        for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
        {
            if(images[i].complete==true)
            {
                if(checkFlag[i]==false)
                {
                    checkFlag[i] = true;
                    options.oneachload(images[i]);
                    counter++;

                    delaySum = delaySum + options.delay;
                }

                $(images[i]).css("visibility","visible").delay(delaySum).animate({opacity:1},options.fadein,
                function(){ $(this).parent().removeClass("preloader");   });

            }
        }

        },options.check_timer) 


     } ;

images.each(function(){

    if($(this).parent(options.preload_parent).length==0)
    $(this).wrap("<a class='preloader' />");
    else
    $(this).parent().addClass("preloader");

    checkFlag[i++] = false;


    }); 
images = $.makeArray(images); 


var icon = jQuery("<img />",{

    id : 'loadingicon' ,
    src : 'css/i/89.gif'

    }).hide().appendTo("body");



timer = setInterval(function(){

    if(icon[0].complete==true)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        init();
         icon.remove();
        return;
    }

    },100);

}
```

This is how i am calling preloader in my view,

```
$(function(){
$("#gallery").preloader();
    });
```